# Geth reports it is synced when Lighthouse Beacon is not synced

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, lighthouse

My lighthouse beacon node is still syncing, but if i go to the geth console to check if it is synced I get:

> eth.syncing
> false

Is this normal behaviour? Or is my setup wrong?

[ is there another command I can use inside the geth console to check when the beacon is synced? - or a command for lighthouse? ]

Answer (score 1):

Geth will only start sync process after full sync of Beacon chain. `eth.syncing=false` may indicate that the process do not started yet. Try the command `eth.blockNumber` to verify the newest block.

Comment: I get 0. So that means geth hasn't started syncing yet right? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @WillB would be nice to verify if lighthouse does not synced yet, i never used lighthouse but probably this [documentation](https://lighthouse-book.sigmaprime.io/api-lighthouse.html#lighthousesyncing) can help you